# Xna 4.0 C# Clicking on a model tutorial?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have recently been able to create models on screen and also add bounding box collision detection too it. What I am trying to do now is when a model is clicked on something happens and does anyone know any good tutorials for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question isn't fit here. You can find a lot of tutorials using [Google](https://www.google.com). This site for specific programming questions. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast a **Ray** from your camera and mouse coordinates and test if it intersects your bounding box. You can create a ray with your view and projection matrices of your camera by passing them to this function:

```
 public Ray CalculateCursorRay(Matrix projectionMatrix, Matrix viewMatrix)
    {
        //Position is your mouse position
        Vector3 nearSource = new Vector3(Position, 0f);
        Vector3 farSource = new Vector3(Position, 1f);

        Vector3 nearPoint = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject(nearSource,
            projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, Matrix.Identity);

        Vector3 farPoint = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject(farSource,
            projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, Matrix.Identity);

        Vector3 direction = farPoint - nearPoint;
        direction.Normalize();

        return new Ray(nearPoint, direction);
    }
```

Then you can call **yourBox.Intersects(yourRay)**, which will return ***null*** if there is no intersection.
The whole code is taken from [this MSDN sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/picking).